# optimize pasting text

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

Someone asked me how can he paste a string 1000 times in Windows notepad.
While this can be done easily using editors like Vi, I'm trying to answer his question using notepad only.
So the problem goes like this,
we have 2 options:

1. We can paste the contents of clipboard in 1 keystroke (C-v).
2. We can double the text using 4 keystrokes (C-a C-c [down key] C-v). This doubles the text in clipboard too.

How can we optimize on number of keystrokes required?

---

I wrote a small program to calculate the number of keystrokes required which uses a simple heuristic:
If (value on screen for keystroke k - 4) > (screen value for keystroke k - 1) + clipboard value then doble the screen value using `C-a C-c down C-p` else keep on pasting using `C-v`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TIMES_TO_PRINTED 1000

int main() {
  int clip[100], screen[100], keystroke;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    clip[i] = 0;
    screen[i] = 0;
  }

  keystroke = 0;
  screen[1] = 1;
  clip[1] = 1;
  while (screen[keystroke] < TIMES_TO_PRINTED && keystroke < 100) {
    keystroke++;

    if (keystroke > 4) {
      if ((screen[keystroke - 4] * 2) >
          (screen[keystroke - 1] + clip[keystroke])) {
        screen[keystroke] = screen[keystroke - 4] * 2;
        clip[keystroke + 1] = screen[keystroke - 4];
      } else {
        screen[keystroke] = screen[keystroke - 1] + clip[keystroke];
        clip[keystroke + 1] = clip[keystroke];
      }
    } else {
      screen[keystroke] = screen[keystroke - 1] + clip[keystroke];
      clip[keystroke + 1] = clip[keystroke];
    }
    printf("%d - %d - %d\n", clip[keystroke], keystroke, screen[keystroke]);
  }

  printf("%d %d", screen[keystroke], keystroke);
  return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Clipboard - keystroke - screen value
1 - 1 - 1
1 - 2 - 2
1 - 3 - 3
1 - 4 - 4
1 - 5 - 5
1 - 6 - 6
1 - 7 - 7
1 - 8 - 8
1 - 9 - 10
5 - 10 - 15
5 - 11 - 20
5 - 12 - 25
5 - 13 - 30
5 - 14 - 35
5 - 15 - 40
5 - 16 - 50
25 - 17 - 75
25 - 18 - 100
25 - 19 - 125
25 - 20 - 150
25 - 21 - 175
25 - 22 - 200
25 - 23 - 250
125 - 24 - 375
125 - 25 - 500
125 - 26 - 625
125 - 27 - 750
125 - 28 - 875
125 - 29 - 1000
```

---

Thus using this heuristic we can reach 1000 using 29 keystrokes. I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution, also is there any other way to solving it rather than enumerating all the possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:**

I'm assuming that we can only use the two options: copy all and paste, in particular I don't use any deletions or partial selection. I also assume that we start with empty clipboard and one line in the editor. To get the result with empty editor (line in clipboard), just substract 2.

**Intro:**

Suppose for a second, that we could execute $x$ pastes for any real number $x > 0$, even if $x \notin \mathbb{N}$. If we were to continuously repeat copy all (`C-a C-C Down`) and then $x$ pastes (`C-v`), then we get growth $(x+1)^y$ in $(x+3)\cdot y$ keystrokes, thus to calculate the optimal strategy to reach $n$ we can minimize $(x+3)\cdot y$ under constraint $y \log(x+1) -\log n = 0$.

The Lagrangian is defined as:

$$L(x, y, \lambda) = (x+3)\cdot y + \lambda \cdot \Big(y \log (x+1) - \log n\Big)$$

and the gradient of $L$ equals $$\nabla L(x,y,\lambda) = \left[y+\lambda\cdot\frac{y}{x+1}, x+3 + \lambda \cdot \log(x+1),y\cdot\log(x+1)-\log n\right]^T$$

so $\nabla L(x,y,\lambda) = 0$ gives us $y = (-\lambda) \frac{y}{x+1}$ which is equivalent to $\lambda = -x - 1$ which can be substituted into second equation: $$x + 3 + (-x-1) \cdot \log(x+1) = 0,$$
i.e., $x = e^{W(2/e)+1}-1 \approx 3.32$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html). From that we can derive $y= \frac{\log n}{W(2/e)+1}$. To be proper, we should check that it indeed is a minimum, but I will skip that. Observe that the value of $x$ is independent of $n$, which means that in the idealized optimal strategy the ratio of copy all's/paste's remains the same.

**Solution:**

Of course, we might have a problem of executing exactly $e^{W(2/e)+1}-1$ pastes, but the above tells us that we should try strategies that are the closest to that number. In fact, because we have only the two options (no deletion), we are even more constrained, for example for any prime factor of $n$ we will have to execute a step with $p-1$ `C-v`'s. The question only is how to split $p^k$ into groups. This is obvious for $p \geq 4 > 3.32$, so doing exactly $(p-1)$-paste steps is best. For $p = 3$ we have another possible option to do steps using $3^2-1 = 8$ `C-v`'s, but that is worse because $\frac{5}{\log 3} < \frac{11}{\log 9}$. Finally, for $p = 2$ doing $3$-paste strategy is better than the $1$-paste strategy. When we have factor $2^k$ where $k$ is odd, then doing $(2^3-1)$-paste versus $(2^2-1)$-paste + $(2^1-1)$-paste require both $10$ keystrokes, so it doesn't matter.

**Strategy:**

Summing up:

- If $n = 1$ then stop.
- If $n$ is even and has parity $2k+i > 0$, then perform `C-a C-c Down C-v C-v C-v` $k$ times and `C-a C-c Down C-v` $i$ times then follow with a strategy for $\frac{n}{2^{2k+i}}$.
- If $n$ is odd, then find some prime factor $p$ of $n$, perform `C-a C-c Down` followed by $p-1$ `C-v` and then continue with a strategy for $\frac{n}{p}$.

For $n=1000$ this gets you
`C-a C-c Down C-v C-v C-v`
`C-a C-c Down C-v`
`C-a C-c Down C-v C-v C-v C-v`
`C-a C-c Down C-v C-v C-v C-v`
`C-a C-c Down C-v C-v C-v C-v`
for a total of 31 keystrokes.

**Edit:**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/0p3fQwv5) is a simple code in C (because the OP used C) that calculates the optimal value using only two operations (copy all and paste) for any screen value up to 1000, assuming that we start with the screen begin empty, and the line to paste is in the clipboard (as intented by the OP in the comment).
The result can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/ua2Dj8db), in particular the optimal solution for 1000 is 29 (which is the same as 31-3+1, i.e., adjusting my answer to starting with an empty screen).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: I guess your answer considers that initially string is in the file. I'm sorry, I didn't specify it before, the string is in clipboard initially and the file is empty.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne Then you can substitute the first three: `C-a C-c Down` for one `C-v`, which gives you $31-3+1=29$ keystrokes.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne [This code](http://pastebin.com/0p3fQwv5) calculates the optimal solution for your setting, and indeed $29$ is the answer for $n=1000$ ([results](http://pastebin.com/ua2Dj8db)).

Answer (score 0):

I'd double the text $7$ times, delete three lines and double it another $3$ times. Bam, $1000$ copies of the text.

Or, if we aren't allowed to delete the text, I would use the fact that $$1000=512+256+128+64+32+8$$
(in other words, $1000$ in decimal is $1111101000$ in binary.

So, first you double the text three times, and paste it. Double it twice, paste it again. Double, paste again. Double, paste again. Double, paste again. Double, paste one last time.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question in terms of minimal *keystrokes*.  For instance, the last two doubles (from $250$ copies to $1000$) are better done as three C-v (three keystrokes), rather than C-a C-c [down arrow] C-v C-a C-c [down arrow] C-v (eight keystrokes).  You should address that.

Comment: I don't know the optimal keystrokes required. It will be very helpful if you could explain how to reach to the solution. A generalized solution would be even more helpful.

Comment: How are we going to double the string in the clipboard without pasting it into the notepad? please excuse me if I'm missing anything.